# Solr wilcard searches

Tags: solr, wildcard, solr-query-syntax

I would like to search a book by its title. Lets say I have 2 books called

```
"Please do a wildcard search"
"Please do a deep search"
```

and then I do a solr wildcard search like the following:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"BOOK_NAME:\"Please*search\"",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

I was expecting 2 books from this search, but the number of documents founds were 0

[Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser#TheStandardQueryParser-WildcardSearches) I've found the wildcard searches:

I'm using solr 6.

Comment: It should show results if indexed. check again with field name and do commit after indexing docs if you didn't did before.

Comment: what type of fieldtype it is ..? Could you share the fieldType used for the field title from your schema.xml?

Comment: The field type in the managed-schema is: <field name="BOOK_NAME" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to be a phrase query, ie `BOOK_NAME:"Please*search"` rather than `BOOK_NAME:Please*search`. That will try to find the exact phrase **Please*search**

Also, I don't think the query will work unless you're indexing BOOK_NAME in a way that retains the entire title as a token. Either try indexing the field as a string or maybe try using the [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser)

> The ComplexPhraseQParser provides support for wildcards, ORs, etc.,
>   inside phrase queries using Lucene's ComplexPhraseQueryParser . Under
>   the covers, this query parser makes use of the Span group of queries,
>   e.g., spanNear, spanOr, etc., and is subject to the same limitations
>   as that family or parsers

`{!complexphrase inOrder=true}BOOK_NAME:"Please*search"` or `{!complexphrase inOrder=true}BOOK_NAME:"Please * search"`